Replace characters in every word of a large string in the database
I have a column of type NVARCHAR(MAX) in the database of my SQL Server, and now I want to replace any characters of the word in the string.
The string is as follows:
DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Description = 'This is text with far too much xx char xanthic Mix Excise xerox Ox Maximize'

SELECT
    @Description, 
    REPLACE(@Description,"x", "how replace x with AAA MMM ZZZ")

If x is in the middle of the word in the string, replace it three times with MMM. If x appears at the beginning of a word in the string, replace it three times with AAA. If x is at the end of the word in the string, replace it three times with ZZZ.
I want the output string to be like that:
This is teMMMt with far too much AAAZZZ char AAAanthic miZZZ eMMMcise AAAeroZZZ oZZZ maMMMimise

How to obtain the desired output result?

T-SQL is not the best language for this (because it is not a text-processing language). Is there a reason you can't fix this in application code?

@Dai, I have large data in the table in Arabic characters and want to convert it, and the output will be like this.

@Dai I know I can accomplish it in C#, but it is a long process. Perhaps using SQL, I can do it in one step.

You might be able to achieve this in a set-based way, but I suspect it would be awfully slow. A programming language is far better suited.

@ThomA I thought to ask a question and see if there is any solution

If there is a solution doesn't mean it's the right solution, @saeedahmed . You could use a hammer to put a screw in the wall, it'll "work", but it'll make a mess.

I dunno about arabic text, but you can probably use the fact that word starts and ends with space and replace it like: SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N' ' + text + N' ', N' x', N'AAA'), N' x', N'ZZZ'), N'x', N'MMM')))

Is it possible for the string to contain a stand-alone x? If so, would you consider this the beginning, the middle ot the end, or would you convert the single x to AAAMMMZZZ? What do you consider a word? In other words: what delimits words? Blanks, commas, erm dashes, numbers, ...?

@ThorstenKettner Actually, I have provided this example for text data in an Arabic or Urdu database that would be replaced with other letters.

1.) First Create a function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordConvert](@SourceWord NVARCHAR(250))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(250) 
AS    
BEGIN        

    DECLARE @TargetWord NVARCHAR(250)=''
    DECLARE @Words NVARCHAR(250)
    DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @WLEN INT
    DECLARE @I INT
 
    SET @Words = @SourceWord    
    SET @WLEN= LEN(@Words)
    
    SET @I = 1
    SET @TargetWord=''
    WHILE(@I < LEN(@Words)+1)
    BEGIN
      SELECT @C = SUBSTRING(@words,@I,1)
   
      IF @C!='x'
         SET @TargetWord=@TargetWord + @C 
      IF (@C='x' and @I=1 )
         SET @TargetWord=@TargetWord +'AAA'
      IF @C='x' and @I=@WLEN 
         SET @TargetWord=@TargetWord + 'ZZZ'
      IF @C='x' and (@I>1 AND @I<@WLEN) 
        SET @TargetWord=@TargetWord + 'MMM'

      SET @I = @I + 1
    END
    RETURN @TargetWord
   
END


Then use following commands
DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TargetSentence NVARCHAR(MAX)   SET @Description = 'This is text with far too much xx char xanthic Mix Excise xerox Ox Maximize'    SELECT value As SourceWord, [dbo].[WordConvert](value ) As TargetWord FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Description, ' ')



It gives the result

Then Concat the result into Targetsentence or large text like the following commands
DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TargetSentence NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Description = 'This is text with far too much xx char xanthic Mix Excise xerox Ox Maximize'

SELECT @TargetSentence= CONCAT(@TargetSentence + ' ', '') + [dbo].[WordConvert](value ) 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Description, ' ')

SELECT @TargetSentence TargetSentence 

It gives the result

You can use large text also like the following


Out of curiosity, have you considered tweaking your FUNCTION so it can be inlined? It's not too much extra work, but results in much better plans.

My aim is to develop a solution that is more readable, managable, extendable.  it is a step by step solution.,
I do not aimed to develop a solution that is compressed, fastest, optimized but too complex to extend.

I appreciate that, but I don't think making your function inlinable will compromise readability at all.

@FevziKartal It is not functioning when Replace x with AAA three times if it appears at the start of a word in the string.

@FevziKartal The final outcome will be, This is teMMMt with far too much AAAZZZ char AAAanthic miZZZ eMMMcise AAAeroZZZ oZZZ maMMMimise

@saeed ahmed, I will check and modify the solution

@saeed ahmed, I changed the function a bit. Now it gives exact result.

Perfect Answer for this question and get exact result in query

Assuming you're able to use the new (real) regex functions in SQL Server vNext / SQL Server 2025 or Azure SQL, then it's do-able...

First, let's just ignore the SQL part of it and just figure-out the regular-expressions:

If x is in the middle of the word in the string, replace it three times with MMM

For this, use \Bx\B, which matches any x character but only if it's not the first - or last - character in a word (a sequence of
non-whitespace alphanumeric characters).
Using Regex101's Substitution mode, we can transform this...:
This is text with far too much xx char xanthic Mix Excise xerox Ox Maximize
...to this:
This is teMMMt with far too much xx char xanthic Mix EMMMcise xerox Ox MaMMMimize

If x appears at the beginning of a word in the string, replace it three times with AAA

That's \bx\B: the \b matches a word-break (i.e. a space) while \B matches a non-word-break.

If x is at the end of the word in the string, replace it three times with ZZZ.

Similarly, that'd be \Bx\b.

...now for the SQL part:
DECLARE @text nvarchar(4000) = N'This is text with far too much xx char xanthic Mix Excise xerox Ox Maximize';

-- Replace initial leading 'x' with 'AAA':
SET @text = REGEXP_REPLACE( @text, N'\bx\B', N'AAA' );

-- Replace any trailing 'x' with 'ZZZ':
SET @text = REGEXP_REPLACE( @text, N'\Bx\b', N'ZZZ' );

-- Replace any 'x' inside a sequence of word-chars with 'MMM':
SET @text = REGEXP_REPLACE( @text, N'\Bx\B', N'MMM' );

...the above T-SQL demonstrates how to apply the transformation to a scalar nvarchar variable, @text.
To UPDATE or MERGE a relation (i.e. a TABLE, VIEW, CTE, etc) then just adapt the above. Don't forget to have a good WHERE clause so that SQL Server won't end-up re-writing records that don't actually need updating (and this is even more important if you're using Temporal Tables).
UPDATE
    tbl
OUTPUT
    inserted.PKCol,
    deleted .Text AS OldText,
    inserted.Text AS NewText
SET
    Text = REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
            REGEXP_REPLACE(
                Text,
                N'\bx\B',
                N'AAA'
            ),
            N'\Bx\b',
            N'ZZZ'
        ),
        N'\Bx\B',
        N'MMM'
    )
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE( Text, N'\bx\B' )
    OR
    REGEXP_LIKE( Text, N'\Bx\b' )
    OR
    REGEXP_LIKE( Text, N'\Bx\B' );


"Assuming you're able to use" is a fairly big assumption as it is not currently available in any version of SQL Server (as tagged)

@MartinSmith I'm using the T-SQL regex functions right now in my Azure SQL databases.

This is tagged SQL Server not azure-sql-database

@MartinSmith Welp, the OP accepted my answer already anyway, so maybe they're using Azure SQL too, but just tagged their question with SQL Server to avoid tag-spam?

Or maybe they haven't actually tried it

@MartinSmith Ever the optimist!

@Dai With SQL Server 2019, I am utilizing. Would you kindly offer a solution for this version?
